# AnnotationProcessing - create ExecutableElement

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm using [Elements.getElementValuesWithDefaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getElementValuesWithDefaults%28javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror%29) to retrieve annotationvalues.
Key of the returned Map is something extending [ExecutableElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html). I can iterate over the entrySet and check the name of each key but this leads to ugly if-else-cascades.

```
Map<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> annotationValues = 
    elementUtils.getElementValuesWithDefaults(annotationMirror);
for (Map.Entry<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> entry : annotationValues.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().getSimpleName().contentEquals("method1")) {
        // do something with value of method1
    } else if (entry.getKey().getSimpleName().contentEquals("method2")) {
        // do something with value of method2
    } else if (entry.getKey().getSimpleName().contentEquals("method3")) {
        // do something with value of method3
    }
}
```

I did not find an easy way to create an ExecutableElement as key to get the value. Anyone knows one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a map of runnables.

```
Map<String, Runnable> map = new HashMap();
map.put("method1", new Runnable() { ... });
map.put("method2", new Runnable() { ... });
map.put("method3", new Runnable() { ... });

for (Map.Entry entry : ...) {
   map.get(entry.getKey().getSimpleName()).run();
}
```

I'm guessing you want to pass the entry into the method so you might want a custom interface instead of Runnable.